# 'input' was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is the code that I expect it will run perfectly:

```
@echo off
echo.BASIC LANGUAGE COMPILER
:start
set available=0
set /p input="> "
for /F %%a in ("%input%") do set mainline=%%a
findstr /ri /c:"^ *:%mainline% " /c:"^ *:%input%$" "%~f0" >nul 2>nul && set available=1
echo available : %available%
if %available%==1 (call :%input%) else (echo ERROR 001 : UNAVAILABLE LINE)
set input=
set available=

goto :start

:echo
echo %1 %2 %3
goto :start

:cls
cls
goto :start
```

But whatever I did, it just echoes :

> Error 001 : Unavailable line.

Even if I inputs `echo hi hi hi hi`
What can I do? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/c:"^ *:%mainline% "
```

You can have a space at the end of the label, or not

```
.... /c:"^ *:%mainline% " /c:"^ *:%mainline%$" ....
```

Comment: Thanks so much! My base environment is set now ; I can now concentrate on functions!! @MCND Thanks!